# PiCamera streaming

Tags: python, opencv, video, streaming

I have a Raspberry Pi with a camera module attached and I would like to stream the video return of the PiCamera from Python to another computer that have a Python server running.

I succeeded getting the video return with OpenCV (sadly with a low frame rate) but I don't know how to stream it wirelessly. The Raspberry and the computer are on the same network.

As part of my project, it is not possible to use a VNC.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `( stream ) sockets` for this, sockets are low-level network connections  :

- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=686162&seqNum=4 ( rudimentary )
- **https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169398/python-video-streaming-server-and-client** ( ready source code example )